# Сменить порт apache2

Tags: apache, apache2

Сменил порт прослушки во всех файлах конфигурации apache2 с 80 на 81. Локальные сайты перестали запускаться. В чем беда?

команда `sudo lsof -i | grep LISTEN`
выдает вот что:

```
apache2   16756     root    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
apache2   16759 www-data    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
apache2   16760 www-data    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
apache2   16761 www-data    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
apache2   16762 www-data    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
apache2   16763 www-data    4u  IPv6 277725      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
```

Что я сделал не так? И что за пользователь такой www-data? Я его не создавал.

Comment: *Локальные сайты перестали запускаться* — как вы это определили?

Comment: Как, взял и в браузере попытался их загрузить. Пишет: Веб-страница недоступна

Comment: а порт указать вы не забыли?

Comment: )) во как! ))) точно, забыл. Почему-то думал, что должен автоматически определиться. По-умолчанию, значит, 80 только да?

Comment: Укажите в ответе - я приму. Поиск такого вопроса не нашел. Может он и тривиален, но кому-то может помочь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Локальные сайты перестали запускаться

если вы изменили номер порта, который слушает ваш *http-сервер*, то для обращения к нему надо будет явно указывать этот номер:

```
http://адрес:порт/...
```

> что за пользователь такой www-data?

цитата: 
[Пользователем от имени которого запущен Апач, в пакетах Дебиан указан как 'www-data'. Это создаёт путаницу: файлы с которыми работает Апач, могут не принадлежать пользователю 'www-data', и Апач не сможет их изменить. Это сделано в целях безопасности.](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Apache)